# can anyone help me with before '&' token error?

Tags: c

In the below code

```
void tread(gonptr &head){

    int coefficient, exponent;

    scanf("%d",&n);
```

I'm having this kind of error when compiling

> main.c:59:25: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before `'&'` token
>   `void pwrite(PolyPointer &head){`

can anyone help?

Comment: The posted snippet does not match the error, does it?!

Answer (score 6):

As per the code visible in the error message, you need to change

```
void pwrite(PolyPointer &head)
```

to

```
void pwrite(PolyPointer *head)
```

In `C`, there is no *reference* thing, it's all about pointers.

As pointed out by Mr. **@zenith** in the comments,the same is applicable for `tread()` also.

<sup>N.B : Code related to `tread()` function is irrelevant to **this** particular error message, anyway.</sup>

Comment: @zenith many thanks. Updated my answer to add your suggestion.